# Continuous function can be written as an exponential

Tags: complex-analysis, continuity, logarithms

Suppose a function $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{C}$ is continuous, never becomes $0$ and $f(0) = 1$. I want to proof that there exists a unique continuous function $g:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{C}$ such that $g(0) = 0$ and $$ \forall x \in \mathbb{R}: f(x) = e^{g(x)}.$$ I managed to proof the uniqueness of this $g$, but can't prove its existence. Is it the complex logarithm of $f$ and, if so, why is it continuous?

Comment: Note that at some point in the proof, you'll need to bring in some fact about $\mathbb{R}$ such as that it's simply connected.  For a counterexample with a more general domain, the inclusion map $\mathbb{C}^* \hookrightarrow \mathbb{C}$ has no global logarithm function.

Comment: To OP: Do you know any algebraic topology, such as covering spaces?  As far as I can tell, any proof will end up looking very much like a proof of the homotopy lifting property of the covering space $\exp : \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}^*$ (or a direct application of this result).

Comment: On the other hand, if you were allowed to assume $f$ is $C^1$, then you could define $g(x) := \int_0^x \frac{f'(t)}{f(t)}dt$ and prove that that satisfies the required properties.

Answer (score 0):

Since $\exp : \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}^*$ is a [covering space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covering_space), the homotopy lifting property for this covering space implies the desired result.  In particular, from the linked page: if $(Z, z)$ is a pointed space which is simply connected, and we have a continuous map $f : Z \to \mathbb{C}^*$ with $f(z) = 1$, then there is a unique lifting $g : Z \to \mathbb{C}$ such that $g(z) = 0$ and $f = \exp \mathop{\circ} g$.  The desired result is the special case where $(Z, z) = (\mathbb{R}, 0)$.

(If you are not familiar with covering spaces and path lifting, let me know and I should be able to reproduce the proof of the homotopy lifting property for this particular case.)